# How to construct a decimal.Decimal object using the C API?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-decimal

I'm interested in creating `decimal.Decimal` objects in an extension in C. I cannot find any documentation about this in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/concrete.html#other-objects)

Does documentation for this exist? Are there any examples anywhere?

I've found the source code that implements the object in the Python git [repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c#L2622) so I'm sure I could do some trial and error, and muddle through working out the header file imports, but documentation is preferred (if it exists).

Comment: You need to use one of the `PyDecType_From***` functions. Depending on from what other object you want to create a decimal object. Or `PyDecType_New` if you want to create one from scratch.

Comment: I don't think this is a public interface, so you can probably use it but you won't find documentation.

Comment: I'd use the functions, but they don't seem to be exported in any header file :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.10, there's going to be a [C API](https://docs.python.org/3.10/c-api/decimal.html) for this. You'll need to supply your own libmpdec and `mpdecimal.h` header, and initialize the decimal API with `import_decimal()`. (Note that the C-level `import_decimal()` call is completely different from and unrelated to the Python-level statement `import decimal`.)

After setup, you can allocate an uninitialized Decimal object with

```
PyObject *dec = PyDec_Alloc();
```

and then get a pointer to the internal `mpd_t` with

```
mpd_t *dec_internal = PyDec_Get(dec);
```

and initialize the `mpd_t` with libmpdec functions. (Note that decimal objects are logically immutable, so you should refrain from mutating any Decimal object other than one you have just allocated with `PyDec_Alloc`.)

To work with the `mpd_t` of an existing Decimal object, you can do

```
const mpd_t *dec_internal = PyDec_GetConst(some_existing_decimal);
```

and then use non-mutative libmpdec functions.

---

As for pre-3.10 code, there is no Decimal C API. You'll just have to do the C-level equivalent of `import decimal; d = Decimal(whatever)` using functions like `PyImport_ImportModule`, `PyObject_GetAttrString`, and `PyObject_Call`.

Comment: I've based this answer on the Python 3.10.0a6 alpha docs, but I don't think the details of this API have been fully worked out yet - it's likely the answer will need revision once Python 3.10 is actually released.

Comment: looking forward to migrating from 3.9 to 3.10 - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question was about the `decimal.Decimal` class, whereas the linked code points to the optimized module `_decimal` which uses the library `libmpdec`.

The following snippet will work for Python 3.9 for all three cases (decimal/_decimal/_pydecimal).

```
PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule((char *) "decimal");
PyObject *clazz = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, (char *) "Decimal");
PyObject *value = PyUnicode_FromString("123.45");
PyObject *object = PyObject_CallOneArg(clazz, value);
PyObject  *str = PyObject_Str(object);
// C++
std::cout << "dec: " << PyUnicode_AsUTF8(str) << std::endl;
// C
// printf("dec: %s\n", PyUnicode_AsUTF8(str));
```

output:

```
dec: 123.45
```

some background informatin for the `_decimal` implementation in Python 3.3 can be found at https://bugs.python.org/issue7652

Comment: They're writing C, not C++.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You are right. Except for the output, it should not change much the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.9/c-api/index.html says `This manual documents the API used by C and C++ programmers who want to write extension modules or embed Python.`.